# Grails validator doesn't detect violation

Tags: validation, grails

Given a simple domain class, with a start hour and end hour, where the end hour should always be a greater value than start hour:

```
    class Daypart {
         ...
         Integer startHour
         Integer endHour

         static constraints = {
             ...

             startHour inList: (0..23)
             endHour  inList: (0..23), validator: { val, obj ->
                 return (val > obj.startHour)
             } 
          }
    }
```

When using 20 for start hour and 4 for end hour, validation should fail. On a brand new instance that calls the save() action, validation works as expected.

When editing an existing instance and calling update(), validation rules are ignored, and .validate() returns true, even with setting start hour to -32 (the property with a simple constraint, not even a custom validation routine.) I've made sure to .clearErrors() before calling .validate() in the update block to no avail. Any ideas on what's going on here?

## Edit: Adding update block

```
    def update(Daypart dc) {

      dc.clearErrors()
      dc.validate()
      println ("Got errors? ${dc.hasErrors()}")

      try {

          if (dc.hasErrors()) {
              flash.error ="Invalid parameters."
              redirect resource: "campaign/daypart", action: "edit", id: dc.id, campaignId: dc.campaign.id
              return
          }

          dc.save(flush: true)
          flash.success = "Updated campaign ${dc.campaign.id}."
          redirect(controller: 'campaign', action: 'index')

      }

      catch (DaypartException de) {
          flash.message = de.message
          redirect resource: "campaign/daypart", action: "edit", id: de.daypart.id, campaignId: de.daypart.campaign.id
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: Show your update block source code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `dc.clearErrors()`, which removes all validate errors from your Daypart instance.

Comment: No change -- same result.

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild app? It works in my test app: `Got errors? true`

Comment: `dc` has errors since `dc.validate()`. In my demo app I also remove try-catch block and it gets into `if (dc.hasErrors()) {}` block properly.